# Opening local windows file explorer in Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to open local file explorer in Chrome app by providing the path of the folder/file in `<a href="file://c:\temp\"/>` or by any other way.

Comment: What is a `local file explorer`? Do you want to implement a file browser inside your app?

Comment: No. Just open the default windows file explorer.

Comment: Ah, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with chrome.browser.openTab and you already know the full file:// path